# VB.NET Winsock HTTPS Post And Get Request

Tags: vb.net, web, https, winsock, packet

I know Winsock Control system well enough.
As i know HTTPS protocol is 8080 and all the data sent or received is encrypted with its key.

I need to know how i can encrypt the data as the format of HTTPS.

I would be very thankful if anyone knows and helps me with this problem.

Comment: HTTPS uses port 443. 8080 is used as a workaround on some systems, like Unix, to avoid restrictions on standard ports (1-1023) that require root access.

Comment: Port is not the main fact here i think. I need to encrypt and decrypt the request/response data.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to handle this is to not use the WinSock control directly at all.  .NET has [`System.Net.Http.HttpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx) and [`Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.web.http.httpclient.aspx) classes, both of which support HTTP and HTTPS requests.  Use them instead of the WinSock control.

Comment: Software hangs while the data is being downloaded in this method. What to do?